# Where to put App.config file when using a .exe executable?

Tags: c#, executable, app-config

I wrote a WindowsForms .NET program in C# using Visual Studio 2017.

I created and executable .exe file from the Release folder (call it Project.exe) and the corresponding Project.exe.config file.

I move both of those to a separate computer with NO Visual Studio loaded.

I want to run the Project.exe file.

Where should I put the Project.exe.config file?

Comment: Next to it (in the same folder).

Comment: Okay, I have it there. There must be some other reason that my executable isn't opening then.

Comment: That is what exceptions are for, they provide all the "good stuff" as far as messages / types / stack trace / etc. If you do not have one check the windows event viewer (assuming this is windows).

Comment: You also need to copy all of the programs dependencies, the DLLs located in the same folder.  And the .Net framework itself needs to be installed.

Comment: it's recommended to add logging before you release your app or even just try it on another machine , as the release build will not contain all the exception details if an exception was thrown .
Add logging (for a file for example) to know what's exactly is happening on the other environment

Comment: You guys are awesome! Igor and Amy your suggestions specifically got the executable starting up now. Thanks guys.

Comment: @picolino Thank you!